# The absence of a value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, enum-flags, enumdropdownlistfor

So I have a enumflag system and I need to filter by Narcotic, non-Narcotic, Psychotropic, and non-Psychotropic in a drop down list. My thinking was to put the values in dictionary and they viewbag into a selectlist on the front end, but I am having trouble configuring the dictionary to register "the absense of [var]"

If my dictionary is structured as thus:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, string> _medicationDetails = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {(int)PersonMedicationDescription.MedicationTags.NarcoticDrug, "Narcotic"},
            {(int)PersonMedicationDescription.MedicationTags.PsychotropicDrug, "Psychotropic"}
        };
```

I want to be able to do:

```
{(int)!PersonMedicationDescription.MedicationTags.NarcoticDrug, "non-Narcotic"},
```

or something along those lines. What am I missing here? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

EDIT:

Is a bool the right way to go. I know how to do that if it were just one bool, but how do I get both to populate the list? To get one to work I think this would work:

```
ViewBag.IsNarcoticOptions = new[]
            {
                true,
                false                
            }.ToSelectList(b => b.ToString(), b => b.ToString("Narcotic", "Non Narcotic"));

var isNarcotic = filters.IsNarcotic;
            if (isNarcotic.HasValue)
            {
                query = isNarcotic.Value
                    ? query.Where(rdq => (rdq.MedicationFlags & (int)PersonMedicationDescription.MedicationTags.NarcoticDrug) == (int)PersonMedicationDescription.MedicationTags.NarcoticDrug)
                    : query.Where(rdq => (rdq.MedicationFlags & (int)PersonMedicationDescription.MedicationTags.NarcoticDrug) == 0);
            }
```

but how to do that for another set of true/false?

Comment: What would your line (the last one) do? return true/false or add it if it's not there?

Comment: I would want four select boxes in my dropdown. Narcotic, non-Narcotic, Psychotropic, non-Psychotropic. I thought about using a bool and ternarying them, but am not sure how to do that with 2 bools at once in concert with each other.

Comment: So you don't have an Non-Narcotic & Non-Psychotropic enum values?

Comment: I do not. I suppose I could make some, but that seems pig fisted. There are already alot of enums in that category and I don't want to waste space for what might get more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are dealing with *flags*: a drug is either `Narcotic` or not, either `Psychotropic`; flags can be *combined*:
we can well have `Narcotic` *and* `Psychotropic` (`LSD`?) or neither `Psychotropic` nor `Narcotic` (Aspirin). If you have *few* flags (less than 64) you can try designing the enum as `Flags` and get rid of dictionary

```
[Flags]
public enum MedicationTags {
  None = 0,
  Narcotic = 1,
  Psychotropic = 1 << 1,
  // SomeOtherKind = 1 << n // where n = 2, 3, 4 etc.
}
```

Then let's implement an *extension method* `Description` for the enum:

```
public static class MedicationTagsExtensions {
  public static String Description(this MedicationTags value) {
    return string.Join(", ",
      (value.HasFlag(MedicationTags.Narcotic) ? "" : "non-") + "Narcotic",
      (value.HasFlag(MedicationTags.Psychotropic) ? "" : "non-") + "Psychotropic"
    );
  }
}
```

So when having drug kind:

```
  // Morphine is narcotic only
  MedicationTags morphine = MedicationTags.Narcotic; 
  // LSD is both narcotic and psychotropic
  MedicationTags lsd = MedicationTags.Narcotic | MedicationTags.Psychotropic; 
  // Good old aspirin is neither narcotic nor psychotropic
  MedicationTags aspirin = MedicationTags.None;
```

you can easily get description

```
  Console.WriteLine(aspirin.Description());
```

Outcome:

```
  non-Narcotic, non-Psychotropic
```